# Matrix differential equation of the form $X'=CX$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, matrix-exponential

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$ and $\mathrm{Sym}(n)$ (respectively $\mathrm{Spd}(n)$) denote the linear space (respectively set) of real $n \times n$ symmetric (respectively positive definite) matrices. I am interested in the following matrix differential equation :

$$ \frac{d\mathbf{X}}{dt} = \mathbf{V}\mathbf{S}^{-1} \mathbf{X}(t), \; t \in \mathbb{R} \tag{$\ast$} $$

where $\mathbf{V} \in \mathrm{Sym}(n)$, $\mathbf{S} \in \mathrm{Spd}(n)$ are known. The solutions of $(\ast)$ are of the form :

$$ t \in \mathbb{R}, \, \mathbf{X}(t) = \exp(t\mathbf{V}\mathbf{S}^{-1})\mathbf{X}(0). $$

My question is the following : if $\mathbf{X}(0) \in \mathrm{Sym}(n)$, does $(\star)$ have solutions in $\mathrm{Sym}(n)$ ? By that, I mean : is there a solution $\mathbf{X} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathrm{Sym}(n)$ of $(\ast$) ?

Comment: Are you sure about the solution? One would expect $X(t)=\exp(tVS^{−1})X(0)$ in a non-commuting context, as it is for matrices in general.

Comment: @LutzL : Thank you for the comment, I was not sure about $\mathbf{X}(0)$. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your generality, no.

Let $V = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $S^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Then

$$ VS^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 2& 1 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Let $X(0) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix} $, the corresponding solution to the ODE is

$$ X(t) = \begin{pmatrix} e^{3t} & 1  \\ e^{3t} & -2 \end{pmatrix} $$

which is not symmetric.